# check whether %include statement is exist in sas code or not

Tags: sas

I have SAS code in which there is following line of code is included

% include "/sas/dev/compare.sas";

it is at location on server
/sas/cpm/dev/code

So, at present what I am doing manually go to above path and open each .sas code(in a Folder, you can say there are 4 codes location at /sas/cpm/dev/code) and check whether %include "/sas/dev/compare.sas" line of code is present or not

Can anyone help me without checking/open manually .sas code how to check whether %include "/sas/dev/compare.sas"; is exist or not

Can anyone , please help me how to write in sas,
We can pass each code through macro right

Thanks

Comment: Isn't that what the unix `grep` command is for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by:

- Listing all the .sas files in each folder,
- Create a datasetp / infile statement for each file,
- Search each line in the file for `% include "/sas/dev/compare.sas";`
- If line is found, print to the log the file name and line number

Code:

```
%let extension=sas;
%let FolderPath=\\sas\SASDATA\momo\;
%macro check_file_path(f=);
DATA _null_;
infile "&f" dsd ;
length string $200.;
input string $;
if string=&check. then put "&f. " "includes @ line " _N_= ;
run;
%mend;

Data List_files;
    rc=FILENAME('FMyRep',"&FolderPath");
    did=DOPEN('FMyRep');
    memcnt=DNUM(did);
    *count number of members  - including subfolders;
    DO i=1 TO memcnt;
        *for each member, test extension and store filename;
        filevar=LOWCASE(DREAD(did,i));
        file_path=cats("&FolderPath.",filevar);
        IF LOWCASE(SCAN(filevar,-1,".")) EQ LOWCASE("&extension") THEN
            OUTPUT;
    END;
    rc=DCLOSE(did);
    rc=FILENAME('FMyRep');
    KEEP filevar file_path;
RUN;
data _null_;
set List_files;
    call execute('%check_file_path(f='||file_path||')');
    put file_path=;
run;
```

Output:

```
file_path=\\sas\SASDATA\momo\file1.sas
file_path=\\sas\SASDATA\momo\file2.sas
file_path=\\sas\SASDATA\momo\file3.sas
file_path=\\sas\SASDATA\momo\file4.sas
```

Log: file4.sas is the only one that doesn't have this `% include "/sas/dev/compare.sas";`

```
\\sas\SASDATA\momo\file1.sas includes @ line _N_=1
\\sas\SASDATA\momo\file2.sas includes @ line _N_=1
\\sas\SASDATA\momo\file4.sas includes @ line _N_=1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, will try this

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by using fileexist function

```
%let  myfile = "/sas/dev/compare.sas";
  %macro filecheck;
  %if %sysfunc(fileexist(&myfile)) 
  %then % include "/sas/dev/compare.sas";
   %else  %put The external file &myfile does not exist.;
  %mend;       
  %filecheck;
```

Comment: it isn't above file check, it is whether %include statement has been present in .sas code or not

Comment: %if %sysfunc(fileexist(&myfile))  check whether file is there or not and if it is there then it will execute the code, else it say file does not exist